# Python: How to read Chinese character from JSON file?

Tags: python, json, csv, character-encoding, encode

I am writing a Python program to read information from a JSON file, then write the information to a csv file. The JSON file contains English and Chinese Characters. However, the csv file generated could not show the Chinese character, but display some strange characters (like æ•¸).

Below is part of my program

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

with open('file.json') as data_file:
  data_teacher = json.load(data_file)

topic[worksheet] = data_teacher[worksheetID]['Topic']
sys.stdout = open('Worksheet.csv','w')
sys.stdout.write(str(topic[worksheet].encode('utf-8')))
```

How should I modify my program so it could allow Chinese characters to be displayed in the csv file?

Comment: Does your program start with a magic line? (e.g. # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-)

Answer (score 8):

To keep the Chinese character in output, use `ensure_ascii = False`

```
with codecs.open(outputfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(datafile, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) function to read\write from utf-8 files. The usage might look like this:

```
import codecs 

with codecs.open('file.json', 'r', 'utf-8') as data_file:
  data_teacher = json.load(data_file, 'utf-8')

topic[worksheet] = data_teacher[worksheetID]['Topic']
out = codecs.open('Worksheet.csv', 'w', 'utf-8')
out.write(topic[worksheet])
```

This function has always helped me with russian letters.